# Multi-label one-hot encoding

Tags: python, multilabel-classification, one-hot-encoding

So im having this paticular problem triying to do one hot encoding on multilabel data, the encoder is reading more classes than it should, and i dont know why.

let me show you:

Here's my data (17 classes)

```
#'Admisión_de_Aire','Antisurge','Compresión','Control','Electrónico','Eléctrico','Enfriamiento','Escape','Gas_Combustible','Lubricación','Mecánico','Normal','Proceso','Sellos','Surge','Vibración','Válvulas'

>>>in: y

>>> Out:
357      Normal
1776     Normal
1777     Normal
1778     Normal
11927    Normal
          ...  
67226    Normal
67227    Normal
67682    Normal
67704    Normal
67707    Normal
Name: CLASS_TARGET, Length: 39519, dtype: object
```

---

running the code

```
 >>>in:
 # Encode
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    label_encoder.fit(y)
    num_classes = len(label_encoder)
    print('num classes:',num_classes)
    y.describe() #double check clasess

>>> Out:
    num classes: 49   #Reads 32 more classes?

    count      39519
    unique        17  #Describe finds 17 classes
    top       Normal
    freq       32266
    Name: CLASS_TARGET, dtype: object
```

With those 32 more classes it finds, i get this result, but i dont know why this happen any suggestion?.

```
     >>>in:
label_encoder.class_to_index
    
    >>> Out:
{'A': 0,
 'C': 1,
 'E': 2,
 'G': 3,
 'L': 4,
 'M': 5,
 'N': 6,
 'P': 7,
 'S': 8,
 'V': 9,
 '_': 10,
 'a': 11,
 'b': 12,
 'c': 13,
 'd': 14,
 'e': 15,
 'f': 16,
 'g': 17,
 'i': 18,
 'l': 19,
 'm': 20,
 'n': 21,
 'o': 22,
 'p': 23,
 'r': 24,
 's': 25,
 't': 26,
 'u': 27,
 'v': 28,
 'á': 29,
 'é': 30,
 'ó': 31,
 'Admisión_de_Aire': 0,
 'Antisurge': 1,
 'Compresión': 2,
 'Control': 3,
 'Electrónico': 4,
 'Eléctrico': 5,
 'Enfriamiento': 6,
 'Escape': 7,
 'Gas_Combustible': 8,
 'Lubricación': 9,
 'Mecánico': 10,
 'Normal': 11,
 'Proceso': 12,
 'Sellos': 13,
 'Surge': 14,
 'Vibración': 15,
 'Válvulas': 16}
```

this is how the encoder works

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter
from typing import List, Sequence, Tuple
class LabelEncoder(object):
    """Label encoder for tag labels."""
    def __init__(self, class_to_index={}):
        self.class_to_index = class_to_index
        self.index_to_class = {v: k for k, v in self.class_to_index.items()}
        self.classes = list(self.class_to_index.keys())

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.class_to_index)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<LabelEncoder(num_classes={len(self)})>"

    def fit(self, y):
        classes = np.unique(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(y)))
        for i, class_ in enumerate(classes):
            self.class_to_index[class_] = i
        self.index_to_class = {v: k for k, v in self.class_to_index.items()}
        self.classes = list(self.class_to_index.keys())
        return self

    def encode(self, y: pd.Series) -> np.ndarray:
        """Encode a collection of labels using (multilabel) one-hot encoding.
        Args:
            y (pd.Series): Collection of labels as a pandas Series object.
        Returns:
            Labels as (multilabel) one-hot encodings
        """
        y_one_hot = np.zeros((len(y), len(self.class_to_index)), dtype=int)
        for i, item in enumerate(y):
            for class_ in item:
                y_one_hot[i][self.class_to_index[class_]] = 1
        return y_one_hot

    def decode(self, y):
        classes = []
        for i, item in enumerate(y):
            indices = np.where(item == 1)[0]
            classes.append([self.index_to_class[index] for index in indices])
        return classes

    def save(self, fp):
        with open(fp, 'w') as fp:
            contents = {'class_to_index': self.class_to_index}
            json.dump(contents, fp, indent=4, sort_keys=False)

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, fp):
        with open(fp, 'r') as fp:
            kwargs = json.load(fp=fp)
        return cls(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code processes symbols instead of words.

Fixes

```py
# classes = np.unique(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(y)))
classes = np.unique(y)

# for class_ in item:
#     y_one_hot[i][self.class_to_index[class_]] = 1
y_one_hot[i][self.class_to_index[item]] = 1
```

Also, take a look at [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn-preprocessing-onehotencoder)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

label_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
label_encoder.fit(y.to_frame())
label_encoder.transform(y.to_frame())
```